# Is there a way to use ruby in a node environment on Travis CI?

Tags: ruby, node.js, travis-ci

I'm stuck with a problem. I have to test a certain task that compiles .scss files into .css in my Travis CI. To do this, I need ruby and sass installed in my environment. But since I'm developing a node.js app and I'm using a node setup, I don't know how I can include ruby in my Travis environment.

Here's my very simple travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "0.11"
  - "0.10"
script:
  'mocha test/test.js'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently all environments have ruby installed, so I just need to install the `sass` gem.

Add the following inside my `.travis.yml` file worked.

```
before_install: gem install sass
```